# Callback of multiple AJAX calls in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
var results = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   $.ajax(... results.push(response));
}
```

I want to know when those 4 ajax calls are done, and then do something with the results array, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating a `results` array in advance, create an array of *promises* (`$.ajax` calls count as promises), and then you can use `Promise.all` on the array. Once all calls resolve, the `Promise.all` will resolve to an array of the four responses:

```
const promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  promises.push($.ajax(....));
}
Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
  // do stuff with results
})
.catch((err) => {
  // handle errors
});
```

Comment: thank you, I figured I could also have a counter that increases with each .done() callback and then check if the counter equals the amount of ajax calls and then do something, but I'm using your solution as it seems more elegant...

Comment: Indeed, this way is better than mine since it allows for error handling. Promises are also a neat feature. I'll point out that the array should properly be a constant (as it is already) lest it be reassigned before the promises complete. This is a concise and thorough answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a counter that increments when each AJAX request returns. When the counter equals 4, you can do something with the results array.

(I am responding with pseudo code as well, since I am typing this on my cell phone.)

```
var counter = 0;
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    $.ajax(..., function(resp) {
        counter++;
        results.push(resp);

        if (counter == 4) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using the other answer but this works too, thanks!